# How to check empty in realmResult from kotlin-android?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I used

```
if(realmResults.isEmpty()) {action...}
```

or

```
if(realmResults.isNullOrEmpty()) {action...]
```

there's false but action..
What's wrong!? 홍홍...T0T

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want to do. Also you can use [google translator](https://translate.google.com/).

Comment: Evidently, the realmResults is not empty.